# Firewall "SimpleWall" opensource code not compiling

Tags: c++, firewall

Downloaded firewall "SimpleWall" code from its opensource location https://github.com/henrypp/simplewall

I am trying to compile it with Visual Studio.

However there are a lot of function like "_R_CALLBACK_OBJECT_CLEANUP", "_r_str_printf", "_r_str_cat", "_r_str_copy", etc. are not found (at compile time).

Most of the `_r_` functions are defined in routine.cpp file in HenryPP's another github repository "https://github.com/henrypp/routine", which is used in this (simplewall) code as well, but a lot of these are nowhere to be found.

Since this is opensource, I assume that it is a compilable source, but I am lost.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but I suspect by your description you either (1) need to download and build the `routine` library (if it is a library) and then compile simplewall, or (2) download routine and make sure the includes are in your include-search-path and compile `routine` along with simplewall..There are both a `.vcxproj` and `.sln` files for VS so that should provide a list of the needed resources.

Comment: The "routine" does not build a library. I off course have satisfied all the include paths in visual studio and have given the appropriate paths to the routine directory where there is routine.cpp and routine.hpp. So all the errors to the "include ..." lines are resolved, but the functions are still not found. Is it too much to assume that the open-source is compilable / buildable?

Comment: The `routine` repo is a submodule. Read about how to work with submodules in an introduction to Git.

Comment: This is not about how to work with Git sub modules. I have a very simple source code of SimpleWall and I have given it all the include files that it needs. It still comes out with function not found errors. I have searched through all of HenryPP's sub modules for this function, no where to be found. Taking a chance if somebody ever compiled SimpleWall source code or if "_r_str_copy" function is in some standard c++ library that I was not aware of. And remember this is a compile time error, mainly a .hpp or .h file issue (not about some library code dll or lib).